# Unknown data type: "USER"; SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mybatis

My goal is to do insert to a table if the user has access.

What I've tried:

1. I tried to execute the SQL statement in MySQL, without the `#{createUser.username}`, I use real value e.g `'admin'`. It works as expected.

This is the statement I use:

```
@Mapper
public interface OrganizationMapper {
    @Insert("WITH temp AS (" +
          "   SELECT 1 " +
          "   FROM organization_member " +
          "   WHERE user=#{user} AND role='0' " +
          ") " +
          "INSERT INTO user (user, password, enabled) " +
          "SELECT * FROM (SELECT #{createUser.user} AS user, #{createUser.password} AS password, #{createUser.enabled} AS enabled) " +
          "WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp) ")
  boolean createUser(String user, CreateUserModelDto createUser);
}
```

My expected result that the SQL statement will insert 1 row of data.

My actual result:

```
### SQL: WITH temp AS (   SELECT 1    FROM organization_member    WHERE user=? AND role='0' ) INSERT INTO user (user, password, enabled) SELECT * FROM (SELECT ? AS user, ? AS password, ? AS enabled) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp)
### Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Unknown data type: "USER"; SQL statement:
```

I suspect this is a bug? The solution is to use CAST but I am not sure why I need it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

User is a reserved Keyword. I suggest you use [] to differentiate it with the keyword. i.e. [user] Should work fine

In case of mysql:

```
SELECT 1    FROM organization_member    WHERE `user`=? AND role='0'
```

Comment: The issue is `SELECT * FROM (SELECT (#{createUser.username} AS user ...)`. The WITH clause is not the problem.

Comment: I know. you can just update your code. My point is enclose all "user" with **` `**